# Spliting each value in Javascript array by list of different values in sequence & then group them

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, handlebars.js, lodash

I have a Javascript array. I want to split each value in the array based on certain value & then group them.

Here are the conditions/values in order on priority based on which I want to split the values in array.

1. `.&`  first split by `.&`
2. `.[All]` if `.&` is not found, split based on `.[All]`
3. `.` if `.&` and `.[All]` is not found split based on `.`

Then I need to join all the values which are grouped together by `,`.

I am able to do all this & here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayx8ceLw/) example of the same.

**Problem**: Now I want to split on following values in the below mentioned order

1. `.&`
2. `.[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER`   --- **newly added condition**
3. `.[All]`
4. `.`

**The fiddle i attached is showing following output:**

```
{ [Dim1].[Att].&[001], [Dim1].[Att].&[002] } * { [Dim1].[Att].[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER } * { [Dim3].[Att].[All].Children } * { [Dim4].[Att].[All].Children } * { [M1].[One], [M1].[Two] }
```

**I want the output to be changed to**

```
{ [Dim1].[Att].&[001], [Dim1].[Att].&[002] , [Dim1].[Att].[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER } * { [Dim3].[Att].[All].Children } * { [Dim4].[Att].[All].Children } * { [M1].[One], [M1].[Two] }
```

Currently when I split `[Dim1].[Att].&[001]` by `.&` I get `[Dim1].[Att].&` but if we change the output after split operation to `[Dim1].[Att]` as shown in the below image, I will get the desired result.

[image: This is how I want to split and group]

*I dont want to use for loop to get the desired result.*

Comment: Hi there - we need a wider picture of the problem. So far, it seems that original data should be properly normalised.

Comment: @moonwave99:  I have updated the question. I hope it helps. Let me know if you have any specific question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join `.[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER` in the `.&` group, then maybe you could just replace this literal in the `groupBy()` function? E.g.:

```
var res = _.chain(selectionList)
    .groupBy(function (x) {
    return x.replace("\.\[All\]\.UNKNOWNMEMBER",".&")
            .match(/.+?\.&|.+?\.\[All\]|[^.]+\./i)[0];
})
```

If you want the elements in array to be sorted as well (thus having `.&` elements before `UNKOWNMEMBER` ones, you could add it in the `map()` function:

```
    .map(function (x) {

    return "{ " + x.sort().join(", ") + " }";
})
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kmbubana/3/

Answer (score 0):

## sort and map

You can get the desired output with a custom sort that creates a rank according to the split criteria.

source:

```
var s = [
    "[Dim1].[Att].&[001]",
    "[Dim1].[Att].[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER",
    "[Dim1].[Att].&[002]",
    "[Dim3].[Att].[All].Children",
    "[Dim4].[Att].[All].Children",
    "[M1].[One]",
    "[M1].[Two]"];

// Sort the items.
s.sort(function(a,b){

  // Give items a rank based on what we find. 1 is high, 10 is low.
  var x = a.indexOf(".&") > -1 ? 0 : 10;
  if (x === 10) x = a.indexOf(".[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER") > -1 ? 1 : 10;
  if (x === 10) x = a.indexOf(".[All]") > -1 ? 2 : 10;
  if (x === 10) x = a.indexOf(".") > -1 ? 3 : 10;

  var y = b.indexOf(".&") > -1 ? 0 : 10;
  if (y === 10) y = b.indexOf(".[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER") > -1 ? 1 : 10;
  if (y === 10) y = b.indexOf(".[All]") > -1 ? 2 : 10;
  if (y === 10) y = b.indexOf(".") > -1 ? 3 : 10;

  // Sort according to rank.
  if (x > y) {
    return 1;
  } else if (x === y) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }

});


console.log(s);

// Create output for the groups.
var output = "{";
var key = "";

s.map(function(item){

  var thisKey = item.substr(0, item.indexOf(".")-1);

  if (thisKey !== key) {
    if (key !== "") output += "} * ";
    output += "{ ";
    key = thisKey;
  } else {
    output += " , "
  }

  output += item;
});

output += " }";

console.log(output);
```

output:

```
 ["[Dim1].[Att].&[001]", "[Dim1].[Att].&[002]", "[Dim1].[Att].[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER", "[Dim3].[Att].[All].Children", "[Dim4].[Att].[All].Children", "[M1].[One]", "[M1].[Two]"]

{{ [Dim1].[Att].&[001] , [Dim1].[Att].&[002] , [Dim1].[Att].[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER} * { [Dim3].[Att].[All].Children} * { [Dim4].[Att].[All].Children} * { [M1].[One] , [M1].[Two] }
```